# Android App Rejected Play Store - Build with Cordova and Ludei Webview+

Tags: java, cordova, webview, android-webview, android-security

My Android app rejected by Google on play store with following details.

Vulnerability - OpenSSL
The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via:

$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"

For more information about the vulnerability, please see this OpenSSL Security Advisory. For other technical questions, please post to Stack Overflow and use the tags "android-security" and "openssl."

I did grep as said and found 'OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013'

```
Project_Name>strings  -s * | grep "OpenSSL"
Project_Name\classes.dex: /Cannot find system OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey class:
Project_Name\classes.dex: 0No getPkeyContext() method on OpenSSLKey member:
Project_Name\classes.dex: GPrivate key is not an OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey instance, its class name is:
Project_Name\classes.dex: +com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl
Project_Name\classes.dex: getOpenSSLHandleForPrivateKey
Project_Name\classes.dex: getOpenSSLKey
Project_Name\classes.dex: getOpenSSLKey() returned null
Project_Name\classes.dex: :org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey
Project_Name\classes.dex: 7org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL SYSCALL error, earliest error code in error queue:
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: Unknown OpenSSL error
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: %s(%d): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: %s
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL CMAC method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL PKCS#3 DH method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL DH Method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL DSA method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL EC algorithm
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL ECDH method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL ECDSA method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL HMAC method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: You need to read the OpenSSL FAQ, http://www.openssl.org/support/faq
ml
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL RSA method
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL default user interface
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLAdapter::OnCloseEvent(
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLAdapter::Error(
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: Failed to create OpenSSLCertificate from PEM string.
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLStreamAdapter::Error(
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLStreamAdapter::Write(
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLStreamAdapter::OnEvent SE_OPEN
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLStreamAdapter::OnEvent
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLStreamAdapter::OnEvent(SE_CLOSE,
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSLStreamAdapter::Read(
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: virtual int net::SSLClientSocketOpenSSL::GetTLSUniqueChannelBinding(
::string*)
Project_Name\lib\armeabi-v7a\libLudeiChromium.so: OpenSSL
```

So the story is :
I have embedded [Ludei webview+](https://github.com/ludei/webview-plus/) in my cordova project to overwrite android native webview so that i can achieve better performance for Html Canvas drawing on android devices below kitkat(4.4) and surprisingly it improved canvas drawing performance comaparable samsung's S-Note app drawing app. But unfortunately Ludei is no longer supporting webview+. I also tried other webview 'Crosswalk' it was good but canvas performance not improved by Crosswalk.

So instead of Ludei not supporting Webview+ i decided to use it in our app.
After [online research](http://support.ludei.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201967485-Security-alert-for-OpenSSL-version-with-APK-files?page=1#answer-202136425) and narrowing down i am sure 'OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013' getting added by their webview+ library 'libLudeiChromium.so'.

And this is where now i stuck as Google rejected my app and they are not supporting their project and instead they have released their code here to help out overselves here.

Can Anyone help or guide me in this how can i recompile their library and other stuff to get the updated library with fixed OpenSSL version like 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za so that i can get approval for my app on play store.

Other details:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ionic info
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 4.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.11
Gulp local:
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.7
```

I will highly appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ludei webview+ doesn't provide support now and project has been discontinued. There is [Cocoon](http://cocoon.io/) (a cloud compiler) to rescue. Cocoon provides updated webview+ with these security fixes.

It also provides Canvas+ Webview for the best performance in games.